# How do I get the bibliography in alphabetic order when using å, ä and ö?

Tags: bibliographies, apacite

I write in APA and my bibliography is also in APA but the order in the bibliography turns out as if "ä" were "a". "Ä" should be in the bottom instead of the top.

```
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[swedish, english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[nottoc,notlot,notlof]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{appendix}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}

\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{bib.bib}
```

my `.bib` looks like this

```
@book{
Saljo2015,
author={S{\"a}lj{\"o}, Roger},
title={L{\"a}rande : en introduktion till perspektiv och metaforer},
publisher={Gleerup},
address={Malm{\"o}},
year={2015},
edition={1. uppl.},
ISBN={9789140688262},
keywords={Inl{\"a}rning},
}
@booklet{
LGR11,
author={Skolverket},
title={L{\"a}roplan f{\"o}r grundskolan, f{\"o}rskoleklassen och fritidshemmet 2011 : reviderad 2019},
publisher={Skolverket},
address={[Stockholm]},
year={2019},
edition={Sj{\"a}tte upplagan},
ISBN={9789138327500},
keywords={Grundskolan F{\"o}rskoleklass Fritidshem},
}
@book{
Stensmo2007,
author={Stensmo, Christer},
title={Pedagogisk filosofi : en introduktion},
publisher={Studentlitteratur},
address={Lund},
year={2007},
edition={2., [rev.] uppl.},
ISBN={9789144018904},
keywords={Pedagogik -- teori, filosofi},
}
```

this is what my biblioagrapfy look like, the last two are in the right order but the first one should be last instead of first.

> Säljö, R. (2015).Lärande : en introduktion till perspektiv och metaforer(1. uppl. utgåvan). Malmö:Gleerup.
>
> Skolverket. (2019).Läroplan för grundskolan, förskoleklassen och fritidshemmet 2011 : reviderad2019(Sjätte upplagan utgåvan). [Stockholm]: Författare.
>
> Stensmo, C. (2007).Pedagogisk filosofi : en introduktion(2., [rev.] uppl. utgåvan). Lund: Student-litteratur.

Comment: From the proposed duplicate: at the end of the answer an approach for correct sorting of accented letters in `bibtex` is discussed. It is noted there that using `biblatex` instead of `bibtex` makes it easier to deal with this kind of problems.

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with your question, but `\bibliography` takes the file name *without* extension. So instead of `\bibliography{bib.bib}` you should write `\bibliography{bib}`. Some systems are more forgiving than others and still compile even if the file extension is wrongly included, but my MikTeX system will throw an error. So it is better to fix this.